# Getting specific web page content in an iframe by choosing from a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dropdown, getelementbyid

I have a dropdown list like this:

```
<form name="change">
 <SELECT NAME="options" ONCHANGE="document.getElementById('frame1').src = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="stuff1.html">Stuff1</option>
  <option value="stuff2.html">Stuff2</option>
  <option value="stuff3.html">Stuff3</option>
 </SELECT>
</form>
```

Which loads a web page to an iframe by selecting one from the list:

```
<iframe class="iframe" id="frame1" src="" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Now I want it to load just a specific part of a web page which has an ID called cointainer1. All the pages have this part. Is this possible? I tried it by inserting #container1 after each URL, but the content of the iframe is scrollable so there are the other parts of the web page too. Changing it to not scrollable is not a solution for me. Any javascript solutions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [parseHTML](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) of jquery. You can load html using ajax and parse to display filtered content

Comment: You can filter your frame on it's load and replace it's content by `#container`

Comment: @Aria I don't really know what you mean by that. Can you give me an explanation?

Comment: Yes of course let me try it in my sys and give you back more info..

Comment: @Adam See the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be another solutions to do this, but I think you cat load `Container` content of each HTML page to your frame

follow these steps by JavaScript pure:

1- should make an function to load HTML page as `XMLHttpRequest` like:

```
 var getHTML = function (url, callback) { 
        if (!window.XMLHttpRequest) return;  
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (callback && typeof (callback) === 'function') {
                callback(this.responseXML);
            }
        } 
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.responseType = 'document';
        xhr.send();

    };
```

2- Make a function to handle your Option change event and call `getHTML` by passing your `select` value like:

```
  function loadFram() {
        var src = document.getElementById("opt1").value;
        getHTML(src, function (response) {
            var x = document.getElementById("frame1");
            var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
            if (y.document)y = y.document;
            y.body.innerHTML = response.documentElement.querySelector('[id="Container"]').innerHTML;
        });
    }
```

3- I supposed your HTML code is something like this or would be like this:

```
<form name="change">
    <SELECT id="opt1" NAME="options"  onchange="loadFram()"  >
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="stuff1.html">Stuff1</option>
        <option value="stuff2.html">Stuff2</option>
        <option value="stuff3.html">Stuff3</option>
    </SELECT>
</form>
<iframe class="iframe" id="frame1" src="" scrolling="yes"   frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

try it you see everything work nice.

but you can do it by JQuery by simplified steps by `$.get` or `$.ajax` like

```
 $('#opt1').change(function () {  
            var src = $(this).val(); 
            $.get(src, function (data) {
                var stuffContainer = document.createElement('div');
                stuffContainer.innerHTML = data;
                $('#frame1').contents().find('body').html($(stuffContainer).find('#Container').html());
            }); 
        }) ;
```

if you would like to use JQuery be sure to remove `onchange="loadFram()"` from your HTML.

Or by `$.ajax` like :

```
 $(function () {
            $('#opt1').change(function () { 
                var src = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: src,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function (response) {
                        var stuffContainer = document.createElement('div');
                        stuffContainer.innerHTML = response;
                        $('#frame1').contents().find('body').html($(stuffContainer).find('#Container').html());
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

I preferred to provide the solution by JavaScript pure because you didn't Tag JQuery, anyway the above solutions works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but neither of them works for me. Everything seems fine, but when I select from the options nothing happens. I have other JQuery codes that works just fine, so I don't really understand why this one doesn't.

Comment: What is the problem? can you debug it , or can you see the console log of your browser to check if there is error or not ?, I have tested it before posting it everything works like a charm, I think something went wrong with your code or HTML...

Comment: It says: "Failed to load xy/stuff1.html: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."

Comment: Aha, that is another problem, because you are browsing your HTML file locally such as `E:\Proj\xy\stuff1.html` that error because of security reasons, but there is no problem on host, I was test it in Visual Studio and I have hosted my Web Proj on `Localhost:1368/stuff1.htm` for this reason I did not crossed with your mentioned problem, you should also host your web also.

Comment: See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local) please.

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't say any error, but nothing happens. On the other hand if I try the pure JavaScript version it says: Uncaught ReferenceError: loadFram is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161893/discussion-between-aria-and-adam).